# Why does Resharper want to apply camel-case to private methods?

Tags: visual-studio, naming-conventions, resharper

Is there any way to tell to Resharper that methods should have different naming conventions depending on the access modifier as suggested for example [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Naming#Classes_and_Structures)? I mean for example:

> private methods lowerCamelCase
>
> public methods UpperCamelCase
>
> etc...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, just go to **ReSharper Options | Code Editing | C# | Naming Style**, click **Advanced Settings** and then **Add** to add your custom rules. The extended naming rules let you define things like member visibility, whether it's static, and so on.

Comment: yep didn't see it! Just for information: is there also a way to export those settings in order to import them on other computers?

Comment: @trippino of course! after performing the changes, press the Save To button on the Options dialog and choose Solution team-shared. that's it!